# Force break line if enough height on inline-block element

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm making a site with a horizontal content. My problem is that to get the content horizontal I'm forced to use inline-block on the content. The content are only images and will be in two different heights, 620 and 305 pixels.

The site looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/alekks/2uBLG/

And as you can see the small pictures are in line, but, since there's enough space for the small ones to stack above each other I want them to do that.
I.e. when there's small pictures, the inline rule shouldn't apply, want it to look like this:

```
 _____  _____________  _____  __
|     ||             ||     ||  |
|     ||             ||_____||__|
|     ||             ||     ||  |
|_____||_____________||_____||__|
```

But if I target the class small and take the property away or trying to break the line :after, it just breaks the whole line and they end up under the big images.

Any one have any ideas for a solution? jQuery or not doesn't matter, just want to get it like this :)

Hope you understand what I mean.

Please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a dynamic layout that can have pieces shifting around? If not, just nest the two vertical smaller blocks in a larger one. Then you make the inner ones both `display:block` so they push the next one onto a new line. That or you can float them, but then you need to either clear them or have the overflow property of the container deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the input! No, it won't be dynamic in any other sense than it will continue to grow ->
But the problem is that this will be made into some kind of CMS template, so I can't individually make changes other than on CSS selector level... Maybe I misunderstood your solution? Feel free to make a jsfiddle of your thought.

Comment: Hmm, mine does require an extra wrapper element but as long as you know that two small images are coming you can account for it. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wQNSQ/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My problem is that I don't know when a small image will get there. The only solution I can think of is to somehow with jquery alter the output by looking for the "small" class and wrap it in a div, and if the next image also has the small class it will be put inside this new div. But my jquery skills are not even near any solution near that. :) What's the best practice in these cases? I mean, it doesn't really feel good to fiddle around too much with the output html, to be honest. Anyone got any ideas? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4JgUV/ The other solution I can think of, using floats, has other caveats such as requiring a set width on the container and displaying from left to right and then top to bottom... I wish I had better news for you, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I kind of solved it by using jquery that looks for .smallImg and then wraps this and the next in a wrapping div... then the jquery takes the width of the first image in the wrapping div and sets the wrapping div to the same width, then the second image is forced to break the line. :) Thanks a lot for helping me figure something out. :)

Comment: Glad it helped you find a solution you can use! You should post it as an answer and accept it so future people can use the technique :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery to be able to give different classes based on what size the images are supposed to be.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var set = jQuery('#content > img');  
    for(var i = 0, len = set.length; i < len; i += 1){
        set.slice(i, i+1).wrapAll('<div class="postImg" />');
    };    

    var set = jQuery('.size-thumbnail');  
    for(var i = 0, len = set.length; i < len; i += 2){
        set.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="smallImgWrap" />');
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
#content{
        white-space: nowrap;  
    }
    #content .postImg{
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
        .postImg > img{
            width: auto;
        }

    .smallImgWrap{
        display: inline-block;
    }
        .smallImgWrap img{
            display:block !important;
            float:none;
        }
```